# Анти-в-во/Антив-во

Tags: орфография, дефис, приставка, слитно-дефис, слитно

Известно, что слово *вещество* сокращается так: *в-во*.

А если мы хотим сократить слово *антивещество*, то как мы будем это делать? Правильно: `антив-во` или `анти-в-во`?

Кто не знает, это слово не я придумал, [такое понятие](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) существует. Так же, как и существует антиматерия в нашей Вселенной.

Comment: Зачем это слово сокращать? Такие слова сокращать не надо)  Форма выглядит некорректно по записи (два дефиса) или не отражает семантику слова.

Comment: Как затруднить чтение спецэффектами? А разве чтение ужé не труд?